# Google+ Interactive Post not Visible when fired after suppressing Google+ Signin "Welcome Back" Message

Tags: javascript, css, google-plus, google-api-java-client

To disable the Google+ Signin "Welcome Back" Message, this tweak

```
iframe[src^="https://apis.google.com"] {
    display: none;
}
```

worked absolutely well for me.

Overtime in my development I noticed that if you have a Google+ Interactive Post on a page that this code also hides the Google+ interactive post from showing when I trigger it from a button. And if you set the

```
iframe[src^="https://apis.google.com"] {
    display: visible;
}
```

the Interactive post will start working but the Google Signin "Welcome back message " will appear again which I don't want.

My code snippet is this:

```
<html>
<head>
...
<style type="text/css">
iframe[src^="https://apis.google.com"] {display: none;}
...
</style>
</head>

<body>

...

<div class="col-md-2 text-center" >

<button class="g-interactivepost btn btn-danger"
data-contenturl="http://xxxxxxx.appspot.com"
data-contentdeeplinkid=""
data-clientid="XXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com"
data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
data-prefilltext="I have the bragging right friends! Check out My JAMB Pre-Test Score.    Beat me if you can #IAMREADYFOREXAMS"
data-calltoactionlabel="WANT_TO_SEE_IT"
data-calltoactionurl="http://xxxxxxxxx.appspot.com/guest"
data-calltoactiondeeplinkid="">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></i> Share and Brag      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</button>

</div>

...

</body>
</html>
```

I seriously want to know how to make this Google+ Interactive Post work while my Google+ Signin "Welcome back Message" is still suppressed with the iframe css style.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop Google+ Sign-In Button from popping up the message "Welcome back, you've already connected with this app via Google+ Sign-In as ....."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159743/how-to-stop-google-sign-in-button-from-popping-up-the-message-welcome-back-yo)

Comment: @abraham It is not a duplicate post. Please go through the post well. The solution for "How to stop Google+ sign in button from popping up the message"Welcome back.." raised the new issue i described above. please I need an answer

Comment: @abraham After days of trial and experimentation. I have figured how to make this happen and even discovered ways to hide any other Google pop up window on any web page.

Answer (score 0):

No need to post the solution again here. Check this answer on this SO question for the best solution i worked out.  [How to stop Google+ Sign-In Button from popping up the message “Welcome back, you've already connected with this app via Google+ Sign-In as …](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20583754/2664182)