# How to change HTML IFrame element attribute with Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Having a challenge currently with this kind of html iframe element. I have this CSS snippet  in my HTML file like this:

```
...
<style>
iframe[src^="https://apis.google.com"] {
display: none;
}
</style>
...
```

Does any one know how I can change the display to "visible" for this `iframe[src^="https://apis.google.com"] {
    display: none;
    }`  element using javascript or jquery onclick function?

Comment: set  `display: block`

Comment: @samitha My challenge is how to do this with js. that code snippet hides all  IFrame pop ups on my wep page but I want to use javascript to enable the display after a click on a button. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, give the iframe an id attribute, like id="iframeid". Then, run this javascript:

```
document.getElementById("iframeid").style.display = "visible";
```

Comment: I don't have a visible IFrame on my web page. I used that code to disable "Google+ Welcome Back sign-in" from poping up on my webpage. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159743/how-to-stop-google-sign-in-button-from-popping-up-the-message-welcome-back-yo]

Answer (score 0):

Element without display style is displayed by `block`. When using jquery's `.show()`, it changes element's display to `block`. Easy and simple in jquery:

```
$('#link').click(function() {
  $('iframe[src="https://apis.google.com"]').show();
});
```

Comment: Maybe you haven't included jquery? Becouse it works for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/hgvPD/